# let forms : How to access destructured symbols in a macro?

Tags: macros, clojure, destructuring

I'm trying to write a macro which expands to a let form with destructuring. My problem is that I would like to have the list of the symbols that are defined in the let form, including those obtained by destruturing.

**Use case**

I'm trying to factor out this kind of behavior, for validation for example :

```
(let [a (foo bar)
      {x :x,
       y :y,
       {u :u, v: v :as nested-map} :nested} some-map]
  (and x y nested-map u v ; testing truthiness
       (valid-a? a)
       (valid-x? x)
       (valid-y? y)
       (valid-nested? nested-map)
       (valid-u-and-v? u v)
       ))
```

**Proposed solution**

It would be really nice to achieve this through some sort of `and-let` macro which I could call like this:

```
(and-let [a (foo bar)
          {x :x,
           y :y,
           {u :u, v: v :as nested-map} :nested} some-map]
         (valid-a? a)
         (valid-x? x)
         (valid-nested? nested-map)
         (valid-u-and-v? u v))
```

**What I'm missing**

But I'm missing some way of accessing the list of the symbols that are bound in the let form. If I had something like a `list-bound-symbols` function, I could do it like this :

```
(defmacro and-let
  "Expands to an AND close that previouly checks that the values declared in bindings are truthy, followed by the tests."
  [bindings & tests]
  (let [bound-symbols (list-bound-symbols bindings) ;; what I'm missing
        ]
    `(let ~bindings
       (and 
         ~@bound-symbols
         ~@tests)
     )))
```

Has anyone got a clue how I might do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destructuring is handled by the `clojure.core/destructure` function. It's public, so we can call it ourselves and extract the names of all locals, including those naming intermediate results used in destructuring:

```
(defmacro and-let [bindings & tests]
  (let [destructured (destructure bindings)]
    `(let ~destructured
       (and ~@(take-nth 2 destructured)
            ~@tests))))
```

Seems to work:

```
(let [foo nil]
  (and-let [a 1
            [b c] [2 3]]
    (nil? foo)))
;= true
```

Comment: The seq returned by `getenv` *does* get created at macroexpansion time. Incidentally, there are no guarantees re: order of local names, since `&env` will be a hash map if there are many locals; but this shouldn't be a problem for your use cases, where you want to make sure that all the locals are truthy / not `nil`.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your question. To use `&env`, you'd probably need to emit a call to the locals-checking macro within the expansion of `and-let`. Then there's the problem of the locals from outer scopes -- presumably these should not influence the result returned by `and-let`? I'll add an implementation to my answer.

Comment: Here it is. As a side note, I suppose I should mention Prismatic's [schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) -- it's a great library for validating data.

Comment: You're right, access to outer locals in tests is important. Just replaced the answer with a new one including an implementation of `and-let` based on an explicit call to `destructure`. Seems to work, and on top of that it's noticeably simpler.

Comment: Thank you! `destructure` was exactly what I was looking for. Too bad that it's hard to find documentation on that sort of functionality; yet I'm guessing library authors use them a lot. I deleted my comments from the previous conversation as it is now moot, I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do most of this with a function that deals with the map directly.

```
(defn validate [vm ; validation map
                dm ; data map
                ]
  (and
    (every? identity (map #(% dm) (flatten (keys vm))))
    (every? identity (map (fn [[k vf]]
                            (if (vector? k)
                              (apply vf (map #(% dm) k))
                              (vf (k dm))))
                          vm))))
```

For example

```
(validate {:s string?, :n number? :m number? [:m :n] > } {:s "Hello!", :m 5, :n 3})
; true

(validate {:s string?, :n number? :m number? [:m :n] > } {:s "Hello!", :m 5, :n 6})
; false

(validate {:s string?, :n number? :m number? :u \b [:m :n] > } {:s "Hello!", :m 5, :n 6})
; false
```

You can add any extraneous variables, `a` in your example, to the map beforehand. This would needlessly test for `a`s truthiness. No harm done?

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but although this seems enough for the particular use case I presented, it don't think it's suitable for complex and deeply nested data structures.

Comment: @Valentin You're right. This is limited - I have voted for Michal Marczyk's answer. The Prismatic *schema* library he mentioned seems to achieve what I attempted here and much much more. So I'll probably delete this.