# Clojure let binding forms

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to understand how let bindings work in closure in regards to maps.  From my understanding let is followed by a vector where the first item is the symbol I want bound, followed by the value I want to bind it to. So

```
(let [a 1 b 2] a)
```

would give a the value of 1.

So if I declare map such as

```
(def people {:firstName "John" :lastName "Doe"})
```

And I want to bind the key firstName then this would be the correct form for a simple "Hello Person"

```
(let [personName (:firstName people)] (str "hello " personName))
```

This works, however on the Clojure website http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms they show a different form which also works

```
(let [{personName :firstName} people] (str "hello " personName))
```

Both code snippets work and I understand why the first version works but I'm confused on the syntax on the second.  Is this just syntactical sugar or a duplicate way of working and is one more idiomatic than the other?

Comment: See the section on **Map binding destructuring** in the document you linked to.

Comment: There's no key `:name` in your map.

Comment: Sorry I misnamed the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last form is **Map binding destructuring**. It's most useful if you want to bind multiple variables to different elements of the same map:

```
(let [{firstName :firstName lastName :lastName address :address} people]
    (str "hello " firstName " " lastName ", I see you live at " address))
```

If you were to write this out using the previous syntax, it would be:

```
(let [firstName (:firstName people) lastName (:lastName people) address (:address people)]
    (str "hello " firstName " " lastName ", I see you live at " address))
```

As you see, this saves you from having to repeat `people` in each binding. And if the map is the result of a computation, it avoids having to bind a variable to that so you can repeat it.

Destructuring also allows you to lay out the binding construct in a format that's similar to the data structure you're accessing. This makes it more idiomatic for complex structures.

Comment: user2766755, you can do something similar with other data structures: `(def x [5 10]) (let [[x1 x2] x] (* x1 x2)) => 50`.  Some people feel the map binding destructuring syntax is a bit odd because the keys go after the local variables that they qualify.  (*I* feel that way, for example.)  However, there are reasons that the "key second" syntax seems to be more useful overall.  [Here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/clojure/1214zse2tq/destructuring-syntax) is one discussion of the issue.

Comment: An even shorter way to destructure a map is something like:
`(let [{:keys [firstName lastName address]} people] (println firstName lastName address))`

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear (and not too pedantic, I hope) ...

In

```
(let [personName (:firstName people)] (str "hello " personName))
```

you are *not* binding the key `:firstname` to anything; you are binding the identifier `personName` to the application of keyword `:firstname` *as a function* to the map `people`.

In

```
(let [{personName :firstName} people] (str "hello " personName))
```

you are destructuring the map `people`, binding the identifier `personName` to its  value at key `:firstname`.

---

PS

This miracle is worked by the [`destructure`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/destructure) function invoked by the `let` form. It can be helpful to look at what it does. For example,

```
(destructure '[{personName :firstName} people])
;[map__779
; people
; map__779
; (if
;  (clojure.core/seq? map__779)
;  (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create (clojure.core/seq map__779))
;  map__779)
; personName
; (clojure.core/get map__779 :firstName)]
```

I picked up this idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23216868/1562315).