# What is meant by destructuring in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm a Java and learning clojure.

What is exactly destructuring in clojure?

I can see [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/clojure-destructuring) blog saying:

> The simplest example of destructuring is assigning the values of a
>   vector.

```
user=> (def point [5 7])
#'user/point

user=> (let [[x y] point]
         (println "x:" x "y:" y))
x: 5 y: 7
```

what he meant by `assigning the values of a vector`? Whats the real use of it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`point` is a variable that contains a vector of values. `[x y]` is a vector of variable names.

When you assign `point` to `[x y]`, *destructuring* means that the variables each get assigned the corresponding element in the value.

This is just a simpler way of writing:

```
(let [x (nth point 0) y (nth point 1)]
    (println "x:" x "y:" y))
```

See [Clojure let binding forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441019/clojure-let-binding-forms/23441097#23441097) for another way to use destructuring.

Comment: I'm from Java background, is it like creating the new variable based on the old variables?

Comment: I don't know Java well, but I don't think it has anything like this. It's not creating new variables, it's just syntactic sugar for binding multiple variables at once from different parts of another variable.

Comment: @sriram It is *like creating new* **local** *variables based on old* **values**, but, like Java `final`s, they are not variable. Any `let`  or `fn` with parameters does this - not just the ones with destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

The term "Destructuring" sounds heavier than it is.

It's like visually matching shapes to shapes. For example:

```
(def nums [1 2 3 4 5 6])

(let [[a b c & others] nums]
  ;; do something
  )

Imagine the effect of the let binding as:

 1  2  3    4 5 6
 |  |  |   (     )
 v  v  v      v
[a  b  c & others]

;; Now we can use a, b, c, others, and of course nums, 
;; inside the let binding:

user=> (let [[a b c & others] nums] 
         (println a) 
         (println b) 
         (println c) 
         (println others) 
         (println nums))      
 1
 2
 3
 (4 5 6)
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

The goal is to *concisely* name items of a collection, for use inside the scope of a let binding or function (i.e. within a "lexical scope").

Why "concise"? Well, without destructuring, the let binding would look like this:

```
(let [a (nth nums 0) ;; or (first nums)
      b (nth nums 1) ;; or (second nums)
      c (nth nums 2)
      others (drop 3 nums)]
  ;; do something
  )
```

This illustrates the basic idea. There are many details (ifs and buts, and dos and don'ts), and it's worth reading further, in depth. Here are a few resources that explain more, with examples:

My personal favourite: Jay Fields's post on Clojure Destructuring:
http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html

A gentle introduction to destructuring, from Braveclojure:
http://www.braveclojure.com/do-things/#3_3_3__Destructuring

Answer (score 2):

It means making a picture of the structure of some data with symbols

```
((fn [[d [s [_ _]]]] 
  (apply str (concat (take 2 (name d)) (butlast (name s)) (drop 7 (name d))) ))     
   '(describing (structure (of data))))

=> "destructuring"

((fn [[d e _ _ _ _ _ i n g _ _ _ _ _ s t r u c t u r e & etc]] 
  [d e s t r u c t u r i n g]) "describing the structure of data")

=> [\d \e \s \t \r \u \c \t \u \r \i \n \g]
```

Paste those ^ examples into a REPL & play around with them to see how it works.

Comment: I like that first sentence: vivid and concise. Drat! Why didn't I say that.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring binds a pattern of names to a complex object by binding each name to the corresponding part of the object.

To bind to a *sequence*, you present a *vector* of names. For example    ...

```
(let [[x y] (list 5 7)] ... )
```

... is equivalent to

```
(let [x 5, y 7] ... )
```

To bind to a *map* or to a *vector by index lookup*, you present a *map*    of *name-to-key* pairs. For example ...

```
(let [{x 0, y 1} [5 7]] ... )
```

... is equivalent to both of the above.

As others have mentioned, you can find a full description of this powerful mechanism [here](http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms).

Answer (score 0):

its used to name components of a data structure, and get their values.

Say you want to have a "person" structure. In java, you would go all the way to create a class with constructors, getters and setters for the various fields, such as name, age, height etc.

In Clojure you could skip the "ceremony" and simply have a vector with 3 slots, first for name, than for age and last for height. Now you could simply name these "components" and get their values, like so:

```
(def person ["Fred" 30 180])
(let [[name age height] person]
  (println name age height))    ;; will print: Fred 30 180
```

p.s - there are better ways to make a "person" in clojure (such as records etc), this is just an example to understand what destructuring does.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring is a convenience feature which allows local bindings (not variables!) to be created easily by taking apart complex data structures (*seq-ables* like vectors, or *associatives* like hash-maps), as it is described [here](http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms).

Take the following example:

```
(let [v [1 2 3 4 5 6]
      v_0 (first v)
      v_1 (nth v 1)
      v_rest (drop 2 v) 
      m {:a 1 :b 2}
      m_a (get m :a)
      m_b (get m :b)
      m_default (get m :c "DEFAULT")]
  (println v, v_0, v_1, v_rest, m, m_a, m_b, m_default))
```

Then the above code can be simplified using destructuring bindings like the following:

```
(let [[v_0 v_1 & v_rest :as v]
      [1 2 3 4 5 6]
      {m_a :a m_b :b m_default :c :or {m_default "DEFAULT"} :as m}
      {:a 1 :b 2}]
  (println v, v_0, v_1, v_rest, m, m_a, m_b, m_default))
```

Destructuring patterns can be used in `let` bindings and function parameters (`fn`, `defn`, `letfn`, etc.), and also in macros to return `let` bindings containing such destructuring patterns.

One important usage to note is with the `if-let`and `when-let` macros. The `if` statement is always evaluated on the whole form, even if the destructured bindings themselves evaluate to `nil`:

```
(if-let [{:keys [a b]}
        {:c 1 :d 2}]
  (println a b)
  (println "Not this one"))
```